# How to display list of recent changes on Team site?

Tags: web-part

How can I display a list of recent changes on a project or team site in `SharePoint 2013`?

This should ideally aggregate all apps like documents, news, wiki pages, calendar, discussions, issues, etc.

It is sufficient to show a list of the changed items - it is not necessary (but would be very nice) to directly display the changes compared with the last version.

Comment: The answer will depend on whether or not you just want to show the items that were modified, or if you want to show an actual change log. The first option can be accomplished with an OOTB Content Query web part. The second will require custom code, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Search Results web part on the page. Click the "Change query" button (in the web part properties) and then select the "Recently changed items (System)" in the Select a query dropdown.

Comment: What if I cannot use the results web part?

Comment: You could read the change log. I have an example here: http://www.schaeflein.net/articles/reading-the-sharepoint-change-log-from-csom

Comment: Updated URL: http://www.schaeflein.net/reading-the-sharepoint-change-log-from-csom/